# Note able to decode and displaychunked image received from server

Tags: jquery, ajax, node.js, http

I am receiving an image in chunked encoding from a ajax call to server.
how to display that chunked image in client?
My code is below:-

```
$.ajax({ 
         url: service url, 
         type: 'POST', 
         headers: {
            "accept": "image/jpeg",
            "content-Type": "application/json",
                },
         success: function(data) { 
         console.log(data.responseText);
         $('#imageDiv').html('<img src="data:image/jpeg,base64'+data+'"  height="200px" width="500px" />');

          }
   });
```

but giving the result like this:

��C��C��A���

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In practice, I often see people do like this:

Server support GET instead of POST for image for example, then:

```
$('#img').attr('src', '/images/pic1.jpg?width=200&height=200');
```

if return base64 string from server:

```
$.ajax({ 
    url: service url, 
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(data) { 
         $('#yourDiv').html('<img src="data:image/jpeg,base64'+data+'"/>');
    }
});
```

---

**If you can not modify server code, you can translate base64 from binary in modern browsers:**

```
// Code taken from MatthewCrumley (http://stackoverflow.com/a/934925/298479)
function getBase64Image(img) {
    // Create an empty canvas element
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = img.width;
    canvas.height = img.height;

    // Copy the image contents to the canvas
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

    // Get the data-URL formatted image
    // Firefox supports PNG and JPEG. You could check img.src to guess the
    // original format, but be aware the using "image/jpg" will re-encode the image.
    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

    return dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
}
```

Comment: My problem was that i was getting image in JFIF coded format and i do not know how to display that as an image. Now i resolved the problem at server side itself. Now image is coming in base64 format from server that can be displayed  using the above code.