# Unable to show raw image in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

So I am hitting a third-party API that gives back an image. I am supposed to show the returned image in a div (which initially contains a loading image), but I am unable to do so. I have tried various ways (as I will illustrate below), but none of them work.

The browser network tab shows the request being received and the image is also displayed as the response.

My code is as follows (I have stripped it down to the bare minimum required)

```
    <script
              src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"
              integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="
              crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>

$.ajax
({
  type: "GET",    
  url:"https://third-party-api.com/path/to/rest/api/",
  headers: {
    "Authorization": "bearer value-of-token"
  },
  success: function (data){
    console.log('SUCCESS');
    console.log(data); 
    //data above is logged as jumbled characters in browser
    $('#t').attr('src','data:image/jpeg,' + data);
    //above line shows a broken image
    $('#t').attr('src','data:image/jpeg;base64,' + btoa(data));
    // above line (with base64) says there are invalid characters in string
    // however the  browser network tab shows image correctly
  },
  error: function(err)
  {
    console.log('ERROR')
    console.log(err);
  }
});

    </script>
    <html>
    <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
    <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
    <body>
        <img src='loading.jpg' id='t'>
    </body>
    </html>
```

The lines

```
console.log('SUCCESS');
console.log(data);
```

prints the following in the console:
[image]

I know however that the image is correct because it shows up correctly in both the browser's network tab as well as in postman. How can I get such an image response to load correctly into the HTML div?

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Does this service you're hitting tell you how to use the returned data? This might be relevant as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20605053/note-able-to-decode-and-displaychunked-image-received-from-server

Comment: Have you tried specifying dataType: 'text' in the ajax request?

Comment: What you get is not valid base64 encoded data. Maybe a blob from a database?

Comment: @j08691 Unfortunately there is no documentation of the service. I had tried the solution in that link earlier, but that did not help me :(

Comment: @kmgt is there a way to convert it? The thing is, since the browser is able to do that in the network tab, I am thinking we should be able to do it with code too

Comment: Yes, that is possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using jQuery's ajax method to retrieve images as a blob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17657184/using-jquerys-ajax-method-to-retrieve-images-as-a-blob)